# login form with php

Tags: php, forms, mongodb, authentication

I want to make a login form when a person has just completed  in another form for registration. Now i have this code, and when i finish to complete. I have no message, I think my code is incomplete. Thanks

```
 <form action="conn.php" method="POST">
    Username:
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"  />
    Password:
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />    
    <input  name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>


<?php
$success = "";
if(isset($_POST['submit']) == "Login" )   
{
$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
$error = array();
// Username Validation
if(empty($username))
{
$error[] = " Empty or invalid username ";
}
if(empty($password)){
$error[] = "Enter your password"; 
}
if(count($error) == 0){
 $host = 'localhost';  
$database_name = 'projett';
$database_user_name = '';  
$database_password = '';  
 $connection=new MongoClient();
  if($connection){
// Select Database
$database = $connection->$database_name;

// Select Collection
$collection = $database->reg_users;
$user_data= array("username" => $username,"password" => md5($pass));
$result = $collection->findOne($user_data);
if($result){
$success = "You are successully loggedIn";
header("Location: Articles.php");
} 
} else {
die("Mongo DB not installed");
} 
}
} 
?>
```

php code of registration :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //getting post variable 
    $email=strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $pass=strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    $confirm_pass=strip_tags($_POST['confirm_password']);
    $username=strip_tags($_POST['username']);

    $error = array();

        if(empty($email) or !filter_var($email,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL))
        {
          $error[] = " <h2> complete email  </h2>";
        }
        if(empty($username)){
          $error[] = " <h2> complete username !   </h2>";
        }
        if(empty($pass)){
          $error[] = " <h2> complete your password </h2> ";
        }
        if(empty($confirm_pass)){
          $error[] = " <h2> confirm password </h2> ";
        }
        if($pass != $confirm_pass){
           $error[] = " <h2> password not same  </h2> ";
        }

        if(count($error) ==0){

            //database configuration
             $host = 'localhost';  
             $database_name = 'projett';
             $database_user_name = '';  
             $database_password = '';  

             //if you have database user name & password then connection may be
             //$connection=new Mongo("mongodb://$database_user_name:$database_password@$dbhost");

             //Currently we are connecting to mongodb without authentication
             $connection=new MongoClient();

             //checking the mongo database connection
             if($connection){

                 //connection database
                 $databse=$connection->$database_name;

                 //connection à la collection reg_user
                 $collection=$databse->reg_users;


                  $query=array('username'=>$username);
                 //checking for existing user
                 $count=$collection->findOne($query);

                 if(!count($count)){
                     //Save the New user
                     $user_data=array('email'=>$email,'password'=>md5($pass),'username'=>$username);             
                     $collection->save($user_data);
                     echo " <h2> Vous êtes inscrit avec succès ! </h2> ";

                 }else{
                     echo " <h2> Username already exists </h2> ";
                 }

             }else{

                  die("  <h2> Database are not connected  </h2>"  );
             }

        }else{
            //Displaying the error
            foreach($error as $err){
                echo $err.'<br />';
            }
        }



}
```

Comment: *best advice* - find something safer to hash passwords with, one such as `password_hash()`.

Comment: I believe you have a typo in `$databse = $connection->$database_name;` -- shouldn't that be `$database = ...`?

Comment: i fix this error but  the code not work

Comment: @Fred-ii- my bad, misread

Answer (score 1):

This may cause a problem: `isset($_POST['submit']) == "Login"`

You're trying to do two things here. The function `isset()` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. So you're comparing that boolean value to the string `"Login"`.

It should be either this: `isset($_POST['submit'])` 
or this: `$_POST['submit'] == "Login"`
but not both.

`TRUE`/`FALSE` will never equal `"Login"`

Comment: okay i have make but i dont have any message, i want: when he finally complete the login form it will redirect to a page for members but i dont have any message example :  "You are successully loggedIn"

Comment: now it work ! but when i wrong password i dont have message who can help me ? and i dont have  "You are successully loggedIn";